# List all playlists: No filter selected

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm getting the following error:

```
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)? { [Error: No filter selected.]
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?   code: 400,
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?   errors: 
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?    [ { domain: 'youtube.parameter',
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?        reason: 'missingRequiredParameter',
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?        message: 'No filter selected.',
I20151214-16:56:33.283(1)?        locationType: 'parameter',
I20151214-16:56:33.284(1)?        location: '' } ] }
```

When I do this:

```
    var data = {
        auth: this.oauth2Client,
        part: "snippet"
    };

    this.yt.playlists.list(data, function(err, res){
       console.log("===== playlists ======");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
        console.log("==== playlists ======")
    });
```

What does "No filter selected mean" and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error I had to specify that I wanted to retrieve my own playlists. By default, it doesn't know if I want a specific playlist or all playlists.

```
        var data = {
            auth: this.oauth2Client,
            part: "snippet",
            mine: true //this
        };
```

> Playlists: list
>
> Returns a collection of playlists that match the API request
>   parameters. For example, you can retrieve all playlists that the
>   authenticated user owns, or you can retrieve one or more playlists by
>   their unique IDs